# pyplot: loglog() with base e

Tags: python, matplotlib

Python (and matplotlib) newbie here coming over from R, so I hope this question is not too idiotic. I'm trying to make a loglog plot on a natural log scale. But after some googling I cannot somehow figure out how to force pyplot to use a base e scale on the axes. The code I have currently:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot 
import math

e = math.exp(1)
pyplot.loglog(range(1,len(degrees)+1),degrees,'o',basex=e,basey=e)
```

Where `degrees` is a vector of counts at each value of `range(1,len(degrees)+1)`. For some reason when I run this code, pyplot keeps giving me a plot with powers of 2 on the axes. I feel like this ought to be easy, but I'm stumped...

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When plotting using [`plt.loglog`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.loglog) you can pass the keyword arguments `basex` and `basey` as shown below.

From numpy you can get the `e` constant with `numpy.e` (or `np.e` if you `import numpy as np`)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some data.
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
y = x**np.e

plt.loglog(x,y, basex=np.e, basey=np.e)
plt.show()
```

#### Edit

Additionally if you want pretty looking ticks you can use [`matplotlib.ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/dev/api/ticker_api.html#ticker) to choose the format of your ticks, an example of which is given below.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

x = np.linspace(1, 4, 1000)

y = x**3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.loglog(x,y, basex=np.e, basey=np.e)

def ticks(y, pos):
    return r'$e^{:.0f}$'.format(np.log(y))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(ticks))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(ticks))

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: I see. So plt.loglog() is actually plotting on a scale of base e. Is there any way to get the axes to be labelled correctly though? When I run this code I still get powers of 2 on the axes. Just a detail, but an annoying one...

Comment: Really? When I run the code I get the axes labelled in exponential base. What version of Python/matplotlib windows/mac are you using? Are you using the most up to date version of matplotlib is probably the most important question.

Comment: Bingo. I was using an old version of matplotlib. After updating, it looks much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It can also works for semilogx and semilogy to show them in e and also change their name.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def ticks(y, pos):
    return r'$e^{:.0f}$'.format(np.log(y))

plt.semilogy(Time_Series, California_Pervalence ,'gray', basey=np.e  )
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(ticks))

plt.show()
```

Take a look at the image.

[image]