# How do I make this LogLog plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, loglog

I am new to python and I am trying to create a LogLogPlot, similar to the one in the image below:

[image]

This plot, as can be seen on the top, is based on the equation y=x^2/(e^x +1).

I have found https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.loglog.html , but it doesn't;t make much sense to me.

I have also attempted the code shown in the link: [pyplot: loglog() with base e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312803/pyplot-loglog-with-base-e) and changing my expression for "y", but the axis are written in exponential form, and I was aiming to have the axis written in terms of real numbers, as shown in the image. The code looks like:

```
# Generate some data.
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = x**2/(np.exp(x)+1)

plt.loglog(x,y, basex=np.e, basey=np.e)
plt.show()
```

But this is not giving me the same plot as the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current x-axis has only 10 values, equally spaced in linear space between 0 and 10. You need more values, and equally spaced in logspace.  For example, `np.logspace(-3, 1, 100)` creates 100 x-values between 10<sup>-3</sup> and 10<sup>1</sup>.

If you change the base in `plt.loglog(x, y, basex=np.e, basey=np.e)`, the axis will be shown with ticks at powers of `e`. If you don't change the base, the default uses the familiar powers of 10. Note that changing the base doesn't change the transformation, it only changes the position of the ticks.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.logspace(-3, 1, 100)
y = x ** 2 / (np.exp(x) + 1)

plt.loglog(x, y)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True) # optionally set a tight x-axis
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To avoid the scientific notation, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920233/matplotlib-log-scale-tick-label-number-formatting) suggests:

```py
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y:g}'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: f'{y:g}'))
```

or, to force decimal notation also for more decimals:

```py
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(
    ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: ('{{:.{:1d}f}}'.format(int(np.maximum(-np.log10(y),0)))).format(y)))
```